# SSRS - Strange error with a parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters, dataset, ssrs-2008

I got a problem creating a report in SSRS.

I got a dataset that contains all the id that I need in 2 other datasets.
IDs don't come from the same dimension, and is a multi-value parameter. The dataset that contains all the ID got this query :

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Barley Volume] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { ([70 Steeping General].[Batch Number].[Batch Number].ALLMEMBERS * [70 Steeping General].[Plant Name].[Plant Name].ALLMEMBERS * [70 Steeping General].[Production Unit].[Production Unit].ALLMEMBERS * [65 Batch Process Data].[Steeping Start Date].[Steeping Start Date].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOMEMBER(@FromSteepingGeneralStartDay, CONSTRAINED) : STRTOMEMBER(@ToSteepingGeneralStartDay, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@SteepingGeneralProductionUnit, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@SteepingGeneralPlantName, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM [Supervision]))) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

Batch Numbers are the IDs I'm talking about, as you can see, in this DataSet, they are from the dimension `[70 Steeping General].[Batch Number].[Batch Number]` . This dataset is not autogenerated, so the value it returns doesn't include the dimension (They return for example "1234567890" and not "[70 Steeping General].[Batch Number].&[1234567890]")

For the first DataSet I need them for, this is the query :

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Air Temperature Out - Fact Germination Continue] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { ([81 Germination Continue].[Batch Number].[Batch Number].ALLMEMBERS * [80 Germination General].[Plant Name].[Plant Name].ALLMEMBERS * [80 Germination General].[Production Unit].[Production Unit].ALLMEMBERS * [81 Germination Continue].[Characteristic Date].[Characteristic Date].ALLMEMBERS * [80 Germination General].[Start Date  Unloading].[Start Date  Unloading].ALLMEMBERS * [80 Germination General].[Start Date].[Start Date].ALLMEMBERS * [80 Germination General].[End Date].[End Date].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@GerminationGeneralProductionUnit, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@GerminationGeneralPlantName, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@GerminationContinueBatchNumber, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM [Supervision]))) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

As you can see, in this dataset, the dimension for the Batch Number is `[81 Germination Continue].[Batch Number].[Batch Number]`

In the DataSet Properties, the parameter value for `@GerminationContinueBatchNumber` is :

```
="{[81 Germination Continue].[Batch Number].&[" + Join(Parameters!BatchNumbers.Value, "],[81 Germination Continue].[Batch Number].&[") + "]}"
```

This parameter works fine.

Concerning the other dataset, the query is :

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Germ1 Delta Temp In Out Inf], [Measures].[Germ2 Delta Temp In Out Sup], [Measures].[Germ2 Delta Temp In Out Inf], [Measures].[Germ1 Delta Temp In Out Sup], [Measures].[Germ Nb Sprays] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { ([65 Batch Process Data].[Batch Number].[Batch Number].ALLMEMBERS * [01 Plants].[Plant Name].[Plant Name].ALLMEMBERS * [04 Production Units].[Production Unit].[Production Unit].ALLMEMBERS * [65 Batch Process Data].[Steeping Start Date].[Steeping Start Date].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@BatchProcessDataBatchNumber, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@ProductionUnitsProductionUnit, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@PlantsPlantName, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM [Supervision]))) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

The dimension for the Batch Number is `[65 Batch Process Data].[Batch Number].[Batch Number]`

In the DataSet properties, for the parameter `@BatchProcessDataBatchNumber`, the value is :

```
="{[65 Batch Process Data].[Batch Number].&[" + Join(Parameters!BatchNumbers.Value, "],[65 Batch Process Data].[Batch Number].&[") + "]}"
```

As you can see, it's quite similar to the first parameter value, but this one doesn't work.

If I delete this dataset, the report is running, so it works on the other dataset, but if I don't delete it, I got the error :

> Query (1, 594) The restrictions imposed by the CONSTRAINED flag in the STRTOSET function were violated.
>
> Query execution failed for dataset 'DataBatchProcessData'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)

I don't understand why it works on the first dataset but not in the second, the error does come from this parameter, but why?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Do you get the same error when you just run the MDX query in SSMS?

Comment: MDX Query in SSMS? I can access my Database with SSMS, but not the cube, can I? When I launch the query of the dataset in SSRS, it works fine

Comment: Yes, you can access the cube in SSMS and run MDX queries against it.   Just open an Analysis Services connection to your AS server, instead of a database connection.

Comment: Ok so I tried to run the mdx query in SSMS, If I let `@BatchProcessDataBatchNumber` and the other parameters like this, it doesn't work, so I try to replace it with real values, as they are populated in the dataset, but it still doesn't work, it display me the same error, but not at the same place, in SSMS, the error seems to come from my param `@ProductionUnitsProductionUnit`

Comment: Ok, so what you have is an MDX error, and all this stuff about SSRS and parameters is just clouding the issue.   I recommend that you either heavily edit this question, or delete it and create a new one.   Just post the MDX query that is causing the error, the error message, and tag it with MDX and SSAS.

Comment: I don't understand why it works fine in my first dataset, which take the parameters in the same way, but it doesn't work in the second dataset, both MDX Query where autogenerated by SSRS, they got the same STRTOSET Contraint flags ...

Comment: It has nothing to do with the parameters.   The two MDX queries are not identical.  One has an error, and the other does not.  It is as simple as that.

Comment: Ok I get it now, I tried my query that's working in SSMS, and it's working fine in SSMS, so you're right, the problem come from the MDX Query, I'll create another question, thank you for everything :)